# Overloaded string methods with string interpolation

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

Why does string interpolation prefer overload of method with `string` instead of `IFormattable`?

Imagine following:

```
static class Log {
    static void Debug(string message);
    static void Debug(IFormattable message);
    static bool IsDebugEnabled { get; }
}
```

I have objects with very expensive `ToString()`. Previously, I did following:

```
if (Log.IsDebugEnabled) Log.Debug(string.Format("Message {0}", expensiveObject));
```

Now, I wanted to have the IsDebugEnabled logic inside `Debug(IFormattable)`, and call ToString() on objects in message only when necessary.

```
Log.Debug($"Message {expensiveObject}");
```

This, however, calls the `Debug(string)` overload.

Comment: Interpolated strings resolve to `string` but have implicit type conversions to `IFormattable`. So, if you `IFormattable msg = $"Message {expensiveObject}"; Log.Debug(msg);` you should be in business. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn961160.aspx#Anchor_0

Comment: See this sample on [TryRoslyn](http://goo.gl/eiRtVr), IFormattable is smoke and mirrors, with Format() underneath :)

Comment: You should really be using `ConditionalAttribute` here.

Comment: There is very nice workaround with extension method http://pvlerick.github.io/2016/01/poking-the-csharp-compiler-overload-resolution-for-string-and-formattablestring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a [deliberate decision by the Roslyn team](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/46):

> We generally believe that libraries will mostly be written with different API names for methods which do different things. Therefore overload resolution differences between FormattableString and String don't matter, so string might as well win. Therefore we should stick with the simple principle that an interpolated string is a string. End of story.

There's more discussion about this in the link, but the upshot is they expect you to use different method names.

> Some library APIs really want consumers to use FormattableString because it is safer or faster. The API that takes string and the API that takes FormattableString actually do different things and hence shouldn't be overloaded on the same name.

Comment: Wow this is so annoying when using it frequently.

Comment: Too bad constructors can't have different names. These are weak justifications considering these people write languages and presumably understand this.

Answer (score 12):

Realizing you ask why you can't do this, I'd just like to point out that you can in-fact do this.

You just need to trick the compiler into preferring the FormattableString overload.  I've explained it in details here: https://robertengdahl.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-overload-string-and.html

And here is the test code:

```
public class StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapterTest
{
    public interface IStringOrFormattableStringOverload
    {
        void Overload(StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter s);
        void Overload(FormattableString s);
    }

    private readonly IStringOrFormattableStringOverload _stringOrFormattableStringOverload =
        Substitute.For<IStringOrFormattableStringOverload>();

    public interface IStringOrFormattableStringNoOverload
    {
        void NoOverload(StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter s);
    }

    private readonly IStringOrFormattableStringNoOverload _noOverload =
        Substitute.For<IStringOrFormattableStringNoOverload>();

    [Fact]
    public void A_Literal_String_Interpolation_Hits_FormattableString_Overload()
    {
        _stringOrFormattableStringOverload.Overload($"formattable string");
        _stringOrFormattableStringOverload.Received().Overload(Arg.Any<FormattableString>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void A_String_Hits_StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter_Overload()
    {
        _stringOrFormattableStringOverload.Overload("plain string");
        _stringOrFormattableStringOverload.Received().Overload(Arg.Any<StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void An_Explicit_FormattableString_Detects_Missing_FormattableString_Overload()
    {
        Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(
            () => _noOverload.NoOverload((FormattableString) $"this is not allowed"));
    }
}
```

And here is the code that makes this work:

```
public class StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter
{
    public string String { get; }

    public StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(string s)
    {
        String = s;
    }

    public static implicit operator StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(string s)
    {
        return new StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(s);
    }

    public static implicit operator StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(FormattableString fs)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Missing FormattableString overload of method taking this type as argument");
    }
}
```

Comment: The downside is an extra object allocation every time the method is called and a string is passed in. For some use cases like intensive logging, this may not be desirable.
I haven't profiled this, but it might make sense to use `struct` here instead to avoid GC pressure.

Comment: Looks like the blog is not available anymore, but there's this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807577/3606250) which explains about how the implicit conversions (from FormattableString to StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter, but not the other way around) makes the FormattableString the preferred resolution.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot force the compiler to choose IFormattable/FormattableString over String, but you can make it choose IFormattable/FormattableString over Object:

```
static class Log
{
    static void Debug(object message);
    static void Debug(IFormattable message);
    static void Debug(FormattableString message);
    static bool IsDebugEnabled { get; }
}
```

The cost of this solution is an extra ToString()-call in the method taking Object. 
(The extra overload for FormattableString isn't really necessary, but will simplify finding where you use interpolated strign)

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCEDYAE4kBkD2BzWS9IG9d8liS8QBmFRFAFiQBEBTAIwFcsAKDVgK2YBjAC5IAtswDOkgIZZmASjLkiMcupoBOLhOlzmAOgAqGAMrCATgEsAdtwUKA3MpIBfWC/xUayEAxYc3ACSAGIYFmIywsIyrAA2zOJSsvJKahqqGuRWAGZIXEGSAZwAojaxCQAmaVkkmbXq8Nq6KYYm5tZ2XA7O6Q3ufeQDnhTU8L7+bJxcYRFRMfHMHbZYSXqpI4SbJLn5hcVYZRXM1dv49Q0kTTrJ+sZmlivdTmd4A1nDg1djtKwYGHEkPspodyotKoQkPJhI4kO8NN5xvQkABZbqbC61WyiZgADwADswbJIrAA3ZgAeX4QlEAF4kAB2XqXdDYAwHLgAEgARCjbvJCHjCcSyZTqSJXNyXl8NJgsOyQVx4AAGAyzSLCLi8/mJAjKyUAGiQQqJJPJVIEIh6m0+biAA===

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast it to `IFormattable` or `FormattableString`:

```
Log.Debug((IFormattable)$"Message {expensiveObject}");
```

You could use a neet trick as a shorthand for a cast to `IFormattable`:

```
public static class FormattableExtensions
{
    public static FormattableString FS(FormattableString formattableString)
    {
        return formattableString;
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
Log.Debug(FS($"Message {expensiveObject}"));
```

I expect the JIT compiler to inline `FS` in production.

Comment: Nice hack. Now it calls correct method: [TryRoslyn](http://goo.gl/8ZhgxX) (check IL to see which overload is called). Note: string->Formattable is done with [FormattableStringFactory.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.formattablestringfactory.create(v=vs.110).aspx)