# convert between FormattableString and (str, params object[])

Tags: c#, string-formatting, string-interpolation, .net-4.6

Can I convert a [`FormattableString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring(v=vs.110).aspx) into something used by String.Format(), or vice versa?

Can I somehow convert $"val={x}" into `("val={0}", new[]{x})`?

Or can I define a method that accepts either a `(FormattableString s)` or `(string s, params object[])`?

I am trying to implement the following two methods without code duplication, as a single method:

```
public void Log(FormattableString formatStr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
    foreach (var arg in str.GetArguments().OfType<MyClass>())
        Console.WriteLine(arg.GetDescription());
}

public void Log(String formatStr, params object[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(formatStr, args);
    foreach (var arg in args.OfType<MyClass>())
        Console.WriteLine(arg.GetDescription());
}
```

So that the following two calls execute the same code:

```
var x = new MyClass();
Log($"val={x}");
Log("val={0}", x);
```

Comment: Your question is tagged `.net-4.5` but `FormattableString` wasn't introduced until .NET 4.6. Is that going to be a problem for you?

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I mixed up the .net versions. I am using the one that has FormattableString support. I updated the tags.

Answer (score 4):

`FormattableString` has the arguments and the format string already, so just delegate:

```
public void Log(FormattableString formatStr) =>
    Log(formatStr.Format, formatStr.GetArguments());

public void Log(String formatStr, params object[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(formatStr, args);
    foreach (var arg in args.OfType<MyClass>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg.GetDescription());
    }
}
```

As noted in comments, this has the unfortunate property that `Log($"x={x}")` picks the second overload instead of the first. I'm seeing what I can do about that...

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the `FormattableString.Format` property (I think it is `.Format`, not `.FormatString`)

Comment: @HugoRune: It is indeed - sorry, I don't know what happened there. I was just looking at the docs, but managed to forget in the 5 seconds between that and writing the answer :)

Comment: Actually, I think there is a slight problem with this method: the overload `Log(String formatStr, params object[] args)` hides the other overload: calling `Log($"val={X}")` will first convert `$"val={x}"` to a plain string, and then directly call the second overload with an empty args[] array, thereby preventing any access to the parameters.

Comment: @HugoRune: Hmm, that's annoying. I can see why it's happening, but it's annoying. You'll probably need to name them differently - but you don't need to  duplicate the logic. I'll see if I can think of a way of avoiding this. (I can think of one now, but it it involves putting one method in the base class of the other, which I suspect is impractical.)

Comment: A bit hacky but you could probably use `if(formatStr is FormattableString formattable) { Log(formattable); return; }` at the start of the `string` overload to redirect with an explicit cast.

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar: No, that wouldn't work - because it won't be a `FormattableString`. The C# compiler *either* builds a `FormattableString` *or* it builds a `string`. They're entirely separate classes.

Comment: @HugoRune: I think it may be worth writing a separate question to consider options for the overload resolution side of things, given that it's not the main focus of the question as asked. The implementation and signatures are really separate concerns.

Comment: That would be a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770713/overloaded-string-methods-with-string-interpolation

Comment: There is an answer there using a `StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter` overload and a `FormattableString` overload but no `string` overload, so it never prefers `string` because it doesn't exist. You could use`Log(StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter, params object[] args)`. It seems like it should be a `struct` to avoid the GC but still. I've confirmed this works.

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar: Not quite. That's asking *why* the given methods work that way, and they don't have the `params object[]` parameter. The new question would ask how to change the method signatures appropriately to make a given set of calls work as desired. (And a conversion was one option I was thinking about.)