# Overload Resolution with implicit conversions

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

I basically want two separate overloads for string/FormattableString (the background is that I want to nudge people towards using string constants for log messages and pass parameters via structured logging instead of the log message to simplify analysis. So the FormattableString logging method would be obsoleted).

Now due to the way the compiler works, you cannot directly overload the methods, because a FormattableString devolves to a string before it's being passed. What does work though is to have a wrapper struct that defines implicit overloads:

```
public struct StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter
{
    public string StringValue { get; }

    private StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(string s)
    {
        StringValue = s;
    }

    public static implicit operator StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(string s)
    {
        return new StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(s);
    }

    public static implicit operator StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(FormattableString fs)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This only exists to allow correct overload resolution. " +
                                            "This should never be called since the FormattableString overload should be preferred to this.");
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void Log(StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter msg)
    {
    }

    public static void Log(FormattableString msg)
    {
    }

    public static void Foo() 
    {
         Log("Hello"); // resolves to StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter overload
         Log($"Hello"); // resolves to FormattableString overload 
    } 

}
```

So far so good.

What I don't understand: Why does removing the

```
implicit operator StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(FormattableString fs)
```

cause the call `Log($"Hello")` to become ambiguous?

> CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: Test.Log(StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter)' and 'Test.Log(FormattableString)'`

Comment: Just because you mentioned structured logging: An different approach would be to use/write a Roslyn-Analyzer which detects misuse of the function. There exists [one](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer) for Serilog. One for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is unfortunately still in [progress](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/658). There is also a Resharper extension doing the same and more (support for more logging frameworks, marker attributes, template highlighting).

Comment: @PEterE Yeah I've written custom analyzers for some things in the past. We have our own wrappers over nlog so existing analyzers wouldn't work. And writing an analyzer is much more work and harder to maintain than a simple annotated overload. But yes that would work too and could catch even more things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to C# Specification, [Interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#interpolated-strings), there is an implicit conversion from interpolated string to `FormattableString`:

> An *interpolated_string_expression* is classified as a value. If it is
>   immediately converted to `System.IFormattable` or
>   `System.FormattableString` with an implicit interpolated string
>   conversion ([Implicit interpolated string conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-interpolated-string-conversions)), the
>   interpolated string expression has that type. Otherwise, it has the
>   type `string`.

In the provided code there is also conversion of `string` to `StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter`.

Method invocation

```
Log($"Hello");
```

can be resolved to both `Log` methods, because interpolated string expression `$"Hello"` can be:

- implicitly converted to `FormattableString` as interpolated string;
- implicitly converted to `StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter` as `string`.

Here an ambiquity occurs to compiler and it needs additional rules to resolve this ambiguity. To resolve the ambiguity compiler uses rules that are described in C# Specification, [Better Conversion Target (go to the bottom of the page 164)](https://opdhsblobprod02.blob.core.windows.net/contents/c6aea4f5457448ee818b7292ba695982/8d2a9714f022bf2c96394a883756935e?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&si=ReadPolicy&sig=h%2BFwngHCi0Szic103HYNdjAiez6NMpThjjNNnlsBze8%3D&st=2020-03-22T15%3A38%3A59Z&se=2020-03-23T15%3A48%3A59Z). The rules say that:

> Given two different types `T1` and `T2` , `T1` is a better conversion
>   target than `T2` if no implicit conversion from `T2` to `T1` exists,
>   and at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An implicit conversion from `T1` to `T2` exists
> - (other rules are not important for our case)

In the provided code `FormattableString` is better conversion than `StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter` because

- there is no implicit conversion from `StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter` to `FormattableString`

and

- an implicit conversion from `FormattableString` to `StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter` exists.

Therefore compiler prefers to convert interpolated string `$"Hello"` to `FormattableString` and then invokes method `Log(FormattableString)`.

> Why does removing the
>
> ```
> implicit operator StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter(FormattableString fs)
> ```
>
> cause the call `Log($"Hello")` to become ambiguous?

Because when you remove this operator the second rule ("an implicit conversion from `FormattableString` to `StringIfNotFormattableStringAdapter` exists") breaks and now compiler cannot define better conversion target. This causes an ambiguity to compiler and compilation error occurs.